# How to limit this simple transition made by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the width of a division by clicking on the options I wrote above it, each time by 100px, using jQuery. But I want the width not to become lesser than 200px or more than 600px. How can I do it?

```
<p id="increase">
    Increase the width by 100px
</p>

<p id="reduce">
    Reduce the width by 100px
</p>

<div id="box">
</div>

<script>
    $("#increase").click(function(){
        $("#box").animate({width: '+=100px'}, 1000);
    }); 
    $("#reduce").click(function(){
        $("#box").animate({width: '-=100px'}, 1000);
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: Keep the width in a variable and `if` it before updating?

Comment: previous comment is the clean way to do it. I think you could do the same with css max-width and min-width, but still your javascript would run for nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="increase">
        Increase the width by 100px
    </p>

    <p id="reduce">
        Reduce the width by 100px
    </p>

    <div id="box" style="border:solid; width:200px">
        dsfsdf
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<script>
    $("#increase").click(function () {
        var width = $("#box").width();
        if (width > 600) {
            return;
        }
        $("#box").animate({ width: '+=100px' }, 1000);
    });
    $("#reduce").click(function () {
        var width = $("#box").width();
        if (width <= 200) {
            return;
        }
        $("#box").animate({ width: '-=100px' }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a CSS code to your project,

```
#box {
    max-width:600px !important;
    min-width:100px !important;
}
```

Or use if to check the width of your box before any change.

Comment: It's a nice idea to do it without any JS changes, but this method does mean that if you get to the maximum and then click the "Increase" button additional times (lets say, 3 times) then you will have to click the "decrease" 4 times before you see any changes.

Comment: The if statement was the thing I was looking for. However, this answer also worked without problem.